# Change the id in the URL according to the selected card

Tags: flutter, api, routes, card

Up!
I am a beginner in Flutter and I am making an application in which I have a first "boats" route. I access to the list of my boats contained in "Card" thanks to this route. Then, I have a second route, accessible from a button in each of these "Cards" allowing me to access the details of each boat.
To retrieve my data, I use a fake API to perform my tests (mockapi.io). For the list of boats, the route is "/boats". Then for the details of each boat, it becomes "/boats/:id/details". Here is my problem, how do I handle the fact that the id changes depending on the boat selected?

Here is the method to access the API:

```
  Future<List<ListDetails>?> getListDetails({required id}) async
  {
    var client = http.Client();

    var uri = Uri.parse('https://63e21b26109336b6cbff9ce9.mockapi.io/api/v1/boats_control/$id/details');
    var response = await client.get(uri);
    if(response.statusCode == 200)
    {
      var json = response.body;
      return listDetailsFromJson(json);
    }
  }
```

And here is my boat_details view, where I try to display the API data:

```
class ControlListDetailViewState extends State<ControlListDetailView> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    late final id = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments;

    List<ListDetails>? listDetails;
    var isLoaded = false;

    print(listDetails);
    getData() async {
      listDetails = await RemoteService().getListDetails(id: id);
      if (listDetails != null) {
        setState(() {
          isLoaded = true;
        });
      }
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      getData();
    }
```

And here is my model :

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<BoatsControl> boatsControlFromJson(String str) => List<BoatsControl>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => BoatsControl.fromJson(x)));

String boatsControlToJson(List<BoatsControl> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class BoatsControl {
  BoatsControl({
    required this.model,
    required this.location,
    required this.id,
  });

  String model;
  String location;
  String id;

  factory BoatsControl.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => BoatsControl(
    model: json["model"],
    location: json["location"],
    id: json["id"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "model": model,
    "location": location,
    "id": id,
  };
}
```

Finally, here is my widget where I use this model:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print('ControlViewState - build');

  return Scaffold(
    drawer: NavDrawableWidget(), // Hamburger menu
    bottomNavigationBar: FooterWidget(), // Footer Copyright
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("${AppSettings.APP_NAME} | ${AppSettings.APP_VERSION}",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
    ),
    body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('\n${AppSettings.strings.controlTitle}',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18)
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: isLoaded,
            replacement: const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
            child: const Text(''),
          ),
          if(isLoaded)
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: boatsControl?.length ?? 0,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12, width: 2),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text('${boatsControl![index].id} | ${boatsControl![index].model}'),
                              leading: Icon(Icons.anchor),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(boatsControl![index].location,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      CustomFloatingActionControlButton(
                                        onPressed: () =>
                                        {
                                          Navigator.pushNamed(
                                              context, '/controlListDefect',
                                              arguments: boatsControl![index].id
                                          )
                                        },
                                        tag: 'listDefectButton',
                                        icon: Icons.equalizer,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
        ]
    ),
  );
}
```

Thank you in advance if you take the time to answer me and help me.

Comment: you can create model for the boat and when going to details you can pass the boat variable  to the new screen to show its details

Comment: Oh sure, I forgot to mention but I already have a template, but I don't really know how to use it next

Comment: can you include the model

Comment: sure, you can see my model now

Comment: can you include the widget where you are displaying this model data?

Comment: Of course, it's done!